# Double for loop to iterate through columns B-M and then rows, to get row totals and change column heading

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the font color of the cell row label to red if the row grand total is >130,000. The first part of the assignment entailed changing the color of the font in each cell with a value over 12000 - The code I have right now correctly colors the cells but does not turn the appropriate cell red (the cell in col A corresponding to the row it is iterating through to get a total). Any help would be appreciated, I am new to Excel VBA!

This is the code I have currently:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Question5()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim total As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Set rng = Range("B2", "M41")
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value >= 12000 Then _
    cell.Font.ColorIndex = 5
    Next cell
Dim monthlysum As Integer
For Each Row In Range("B2", "M41")
Set monthlysum = 0
    For Each cell In Row
    monthlysum = cell.Value + monthlysum
    Next cell
    If monthlysum > 130000 Then _
    Range("A" & rowNum).Select
    Range("A" & rowNum).Font.Color = vbRed
Next Row
End Sub
```

Comment: max value for Integer is 32,000 so start by switching all your Integers to Long

Comment: You also have not declared Row as Range, so your code as posted would not compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - fixes commented inline

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Question5()
    Dim rng As Range, Row As Range, cell as Range
    Dim monthlySum as Long 'use Long not Integer

    For Each Row In ActiveSheet.Range("B2:M41").Rows 'need to specify .Rows otherwise defaults to .Cells
        monthlySum = 0
        For Each cell in Row.Cells
            with cell
               if .Value >= 12000 Then cell.Font.ColorIndex = 5
               monthlySum = monthlySum + .Value
            End With
        Next cell
        if monthlySum > 130000 Then Row.Entirerow.cells(1).Font.color=vbRed 
    Next Row
End Sub
```